# vimscript insert string before a search pattern

Tags: coffeescript, vim

Im currently write a [coffeescript refactore plugin](https://github.com/ranska/vim-coffeescript-refactoring).

Currently i'am experimenting an issue, when i try to add parameter to a function.

so far in can do

```
#my code
->
# after call vim function
(new_param) ->
```

but
when now i want insert it just before the arrow like

```
#my code
foo ->
# what i want
foo (new_param) ->
```

i have this unwanted result

```
(new_param) foo ->
```

What i use in vim script is

```
exec "?->"
execute "normal i(new_param) \<Esc>"
```

What should i do to insert just before the arrow.
I read about `searchpos()` but i don't find good example to understand how it work.

Know the cursor position is important i guess for handel corner case like

```
(old_param) ->
#add parameter to existing parameter
(old_param, new_param) ->
```

Comment: you want to do this on whole buffer or on specific line? how about use `substitute()`?

Comment: good idea. Well in coffeescript it can be `foo ->` or `foo =>` so is it possible to subsititute with `"?->\\|=>"` and keep the good arrow after substitution ? In this case it would be perfect.

Comment: can you make a concrete example, like how to change "before" into "after"?

Comment: Yes. So there is 2 case. first `foo ->` into `foo (new_param) ->` and 2nd `foo =>` into `foo (new_param) =>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this command :

```
%s/\s\?[-=]>/ (new_param)&/g
```

will transform:

```
foo ->
foo =>
```

into:

```
foo (new_param) ->
foo (new_param) =>
```

for the adding new_param case:

you could do :

```
%s/)\s\?[-=]>/, new_param&/g
```

Comment: woow ! it look to be what i need. I will try it tomorrow. thanks a lot. I guess i need to read de doc for a better understanding of substitute. Is `\s\` who will change by `pattern&` ?

Comment: yes it work for me. There is a corner case 2 function on single line. when i apply thing like `:s/.*\zs)\s\?[-=]>/, new_param&/` to `foo (a) -> foo (b) ->  bar #cursor_pos` it change to `foo (a) -> foo (b,new_param) -> bar` but i experiment some issue when i put in a function vim told me thing's like pattern not found ? should i change the way i write pattern inside a function ?